# lftp does not connect to SFTP (even after asking for password)

Tags: sftp, lftp

I've been trying to use `lftp` over SFTP but I somehow can't get it to connect properly.

I issue the command (which as far as I can tell is the same as the one for `sftp`), `lftp` prompts me for the password, which I input, and the `lftp` prompt appears! This all seems good, but I can't do anything afterwards.

Here's an illustration:

```
myuser $ lftp myuser@server.edu                                                                                                                                    
Password: 
lftp myuser@server.edu:~> ls                   
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

and then it gets stuck there. Note that if I issue `sftp myuser@server.edu` and input the password everything works flawlessly. Am I missing something obvious?

I'm using `lftp` version 4.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

The `lftp` is primarily an FTP client. If you want it to use SFTP, you have to tell it so:

```
lftp sftp://myuser@server.edu
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this problem because I tried using lftp without trying sftp or ssh first.

The latter programs were prompting me to accept an SSH fingerprint. But lftp was suppressing this prompt, and just showing **`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]** forever.

I had to attempt a connection with ssh/sftp first and accept the fingerprint, which added it to my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.  After this, `lftp sftp://...` could connect fine.